# light intensity through a double slit

Tags: optics, double-slit-experiment, interference, poynting-vector

When a light source with a given intensity I emit through a double slit (or triple slit) how does the intensity of the first maxima change in regard with the initial one?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following the classical experiment of the double slit, the light intensity is given by the Fraunhofer diffraction equation.

### First argument

If we explicitate Fraunhofer formula with respect to the angle $\theta$ with respect to the orizontal axis (i.e., perpendicular to the the detection wall), we obtain

$$ I(\theta) \propto \cos ^{2}\left[{\frac {\pi d\sin \theta }{\lambda }}\right]~\mathrm {sinc} ^{2}\left[{\frac {\pi b\sin \theta }{\lambda }}\right]$$

Where the sinc function is defined as $sinc(x) = sin(x)/x$ for $x \neq 0$, and $sinc(0) = 1$ 
 We can easily check that the maximum is obtained at $\theta=0$.

[image]

### Second argument

Since the question concerned the exact intensity of the light, I would like here to post another possible derivation. Consider the following double slit experiment and suppose there is a Electrical field passing through the slits.

[image]

The total instantaneous electric field $\vec{E}$ at the point $P$ on the screen is equal to the vector sum of  the  two  sources: 
$$\vec{E}=\vec{E_1}+\vec{E_2}. $$
On  the  other  hand,  the  Poynting  flux $S$ is proportional to the square of the total field:
$$S\propto \vec{E}^2=(\vec{E_1}+\vec{E_2})^2=\vec{E_1}^2+\vec{E_2}^2+2\vec{E_1}\cdot\vec{E_2}.$$
Taking the time average of $S$, the intensity $I$ of the light at $P$ may be obtained as:
$$I = \langle S\rangle \propto \langle\vec{E_1}^2\rangle+\langle\vec{E_2}^2\rangle+2\langle\vec{E_1}\cdot\vec{E_2}\rangle. $$

The  cross  term $2\langle\vec{E_1}\cdot\vec{E_2}\rangle$ represents  the  correlation  between  the  two  light  waves.  For incoherent light sources, since there is no definite phase relation between $E_1$ and $E_2$ the cross term vanishes, and  the  intensity  due  to the incoherent  source  is  simply  the  sum  of the two individual intensities: 
$$I_{inc}=I_1+I_2$$ 
For  coherent  sources,  the  cross  term is  nonzero.  In  fact,  for  constructive  interference, $E_1=E_2$, and the resulting intensity is 
$$I_{inc}=4I$$
which  is  four  times  greater  than  the  intensity  due  to  a  single  source.

Comment: in the first argument we obtain the maximum intensity for θ=0 but I am asking about the relation with the intensity of the single light source. Is that answered in the second argument? ( I = 4 Io)

Comment: Yes, it is. The first argument is only an additional proof for saing that the maximum is obtained when tha angle is zero

Comment: Sorry, I've just seen that the question was also about a triple slit... I will edit my answer asap

Comment: Although this answer is good a significant parât of it is basically copy-pasted without attribution from an MIT website: http://web.mit.edu/viz/EM/visualizations/coursenotes/modules/guide14.pdf

Comment: Yes, it is... Please let me know if it violates in some way the policy of SE. In this case I will erase immediately my answer.

Comment: @Erik Pillon you MUST provide proper attribution (link to it!) and state that you copied it from the notes above (be honest). Also, anyone who wants to read further will surely appreciate this.